# Scrollview inside a scrollview in android issue

Tags: android

I have a scrollview inside a scrollview . The xml is like this

```
<RelativeLayout ....
    <ScrollView.....
         <RelativeLayout ....
           <Button.....
           <Button ....
           <ScrollView
             <RelativeLayout ....
                 ..........
               </RelativeLayout>
             </ScrollView>
         </RelativeLayout>
     </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

in this second scrollview in not scrolling smoothly. can give a solution for that. I tried a lot of solution given in the internet but not working.

Comment: i dont think scroll view inside scrollview will work

Comment: can u tell me the exact requirmrnt

Comment: Its not a good practice to have 2 scrollViews which scroll in the same direction inside one another, even if it works

Comment: You do not need to use scrollview inside scrollview use can scroll inner scroll from the outer scroll.

Comment: its not a good practice to have scrollview inside a scrollview, you might want to think of your layout design again. :)

Comment: the requirement is needed a scrollview inside scrollview. the child scrollview is not smooth as the parent scrollview

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this code. It is working for me`

```
 parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    findViewById(R.id.childScrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
return false;
}
});
childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{

// Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
// child view
v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
return false;
}
});`
```

Comment: for me this does noting, the childScrollView wont receive its ontouch whatever i do.

Comment: Can anyone explain what does it do to the parent of the childscroll.. How does it avoid the parent scroll view to stop scrolling and allow the child to scroll

Answer (score 7):

A different solution is to use this class as the parent class

```
public class NoInterceptScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public NoInterceptScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would prefer this as a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

I had to improve Deepthi's solution since it didn't work for me; I guess because my child scrollview is full of views (I mean child views use all of the scrollview drawing space). To make it fully functional, I had to also disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of all children views inside the child scroll view:

```
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        findViewById(R.id.childScrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});
childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
        // child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});`
childScrollviewRecursiveLoopChildren(parentScrollView, childScrollView);
public void childScrollviewRecursiveLoopChildren(final ScrollView parentScrollView, View parent) {
    for (int i = ((ViewGroup) parent).getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final View child = ((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            childScrollviewRecursiveLoopChildren(parentScrollView, (ViewGroup) child);
        } else {
            child.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
                    // child view
                    parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```