# com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView inside the scrollview is not working in android

Tags: android

i am using com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView in my project inside the nested scrollview the pdf view is not scrolling the nested scrollview it self scrolling

Comment: You will have to use trick method to make it scroll as well. think of it as another scrollview inside scroll view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671123/scrollview-inside-a-scrollview-in-android-issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrollview inside a scrollview in android issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671123/scrollview-inside-a-scrollview-in-android-issue)

Answer (score -1):

You have to change `layout_height` to "1200dp".
It will work.

```xml
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1200dp" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes, it is showing now. But now the PDF file does not scroll

Comment: You have to change layout_height ? It is not working set wrap_content or fill_content

Comment: This is also not working, I have been trying to achieve this from last 2 days but not getting any success till now. If I use match_parent then the PDF does not even shows up but with 1200 dp it is showing but does not scroll. As you mention to set_wrap it also works like match_parent does not show.