# Can't scroll ScrollView in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, bottom-sheet, nestedscrollview

I'm using a NestedScrollView with a BottomSheetBehavior. It has one direct child, a ScrollView. When the bottom sheet is expanded, I want to be able to scroll through the contents in the ScrollView, because even when it's expanded, it's still too much to view without scrolling. However, it is not responding. This is the XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.thunderbuild.weegnet.fragments.FragmentBridgesMap">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bridges_mv_map"
            app:mapType="normal" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bridges_nsv_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/bridge_sv_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bridge_mv_map"
                    android:id="@+id/bridge_cl_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bridge_tv_name"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Bridge name"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bridge_btn_weigh"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Weigh"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                        android:textColor="@color/lightTextColor"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_opening_times"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bridge_tv_status"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/green"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Opened until..."
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/bridge_tv_name"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bridge_tv_name"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bridge_tv_status"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bridge_tv_status"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:tint="@color/secondaryTextColor"
                            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_car" />

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bridge_tv_eta"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="5 min." />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_marker"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bridge_tv_status" />

                <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_opening_times"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

                <TextView
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/bridge_tv_address"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ll_opening_times"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"
                        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ll_opening_times"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView" />

                <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/secondaryTextColor"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bridge_tv_address"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        android:id="@+id/view" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17671832/3331812) but to no avail. Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: I'm now noticing that I *can* scroll, but just not far enough. The content gets cut off at the bottom.

Comment: NestedScrollView is the extended class from Scrollview.. it already redundant in your xml.. use NestedScrollView instead

Comment: No, NestedScrollView extends from FrameLayout. However, I still tried what you suggested. I removed the child ScrollView, but having the same results. The full content doesn't fit in the bottom sheet even when it's fully expanded, so I want to be able to scroll though it. I can't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems was that the button had no bottom constraint. I added it and also a lot of margin to its bottom, which prevented it being cut off. It's a sloppy solution but works for now.